# cakephp 2.0 paginator problems

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, paginator

I'm currently trying to set up the pagination on two different models.
In the Controller class I'm doing following:

```
    var $paginate = array(
        'Model1' => array('limit' => 10, 'recursive' => 0, 'model' => 'Model1, 'order' => array('field1' => 'ASC'), 'paramType' => 'querystring'),
        'Model2' => array('limit' => 10, 'recursive' => 0, 'model' => 'Model2', 'order' => array('field2' => 'ASC'), 'paramType' => 'querystring')
    );

    function view($id = null) {

        // ...

        $models1 = $this->paginate('Model1', array('Model1.model_id => $id));        
        if ($models1) {
            $this->set('models1', $models1);
        }
        $models2 = $this->paginate('Model2', array('Model2.model_id => $id));
        if ($models2) {
            $this->set('models2', $models2);
        }
    }
```

In the view, the links are produced using

```
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model' => 'Model1')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model' => 'Model2')); ?>
```

As a result, I get the correct number of pages, but the links are wrong.

1. The `id` is ignored, i.e. instead of `controller/action/id?page= ...` , I get `controller/action?page= ...`.
2. This part of the link `sort=Model1.field1&direction=ASC` is also not working.
   I'm able to open the page with `sort=field1&direction=ASC`. But how should it be distinguished if the first or the second model is sorted?

BTW, all this worked well when using CakePHP 1.3.

Comment: In order to get `id` in the links, you need to have `$this->Model->id = $id` before calling `paginate` function. But I'm still having similar problems with links ...

Answer (score 0):

You've paginated `Model1` on both calls, surely the second one should be:

```
$models2 = $this->paginate('Model2', ...
```